# How to get parent element and then next element by

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I want to get the parent of specify element (span with class is mw-headline)  and then get the first next element of this parent.

```
<h2>
    <span class="mw-headline" id="Botany">Botany
    </span>
    <span class="mw-editsection">
        <span class="mw-editsection-bracket">
        </span><a href="/w/index.php?title=Apple_(disambiguation)&amp;action=edit&amp;section=1&amp;editintro=Template:Disambig_editintro" title="Edit section: Botany">edit</a><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">

    </span>
</span>
</h2>
<ul>
    <li><i><a href="/wiki/Malus" title="Malus">Malus</a></i>, the genus of all apples and crabapples</li>
    <li><a href="/wiki/Cashew_apple" class="mw-redirect" title="Cashew apple">Cashew apple</a>, the fruit that grows with the cashew nut</li>
    <li><a href="/wiki/Custard_apple" title="Custard apple">Custard apple</a>, several fruits</li>
    <li><a href="/wiki/Love_apple" title="Love apple">Love apple</a>:
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/wiki/Tomato" title="Tomato">Tomato</a></li>
            <li><i><a href="/wiki/Syzygium_samarangense" title="Syzygium samarangense">Syzygium samarangense</a></i>, a plant species in the Myrtaceae family</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/wiki/Mammee_apple_(disambiguation)" class="mw-redirect" title="Mammee apple (disambiguation)">Mammee apple (disambiguation)</a></li>
    <li><a href="/wiki/May_apple" class="mw-redirect" title="May apple">May apple</a> (<i>Podophyllum peltatum</i>)</li>
    <li><a href="/wiki/Oak_apple" title="Oak apple">Oak apple</a>, a type of gall that grows on oak trees</li>
    <li><a href="/wiki/Rose_apple_(disambiguation)" class="mw-redirect" title="Rose apple (disambiguation)">Rose apple (disambiguation)</a>, several fruits</li>
    <li><a href="/wiki/Thorn_apple_(disambiguation)" class="mw-redirect mw-disambig" title="Thorn apple (disambiguation)">Thorn apple (disambiguation)</a>:
        <ul>
            <li><i><a href="/wiki/Crataegus" title="Crataegus">Crataegus</a></i> species</li>
            <li><i><a href="/wiki/Datura" title="Datura">Datura</a></i> species</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/wiki/Wax_apple" class="mw-redirect" title="Wax apple">Wax apple</a> (<i>Syzygium samarangense</i>)</li>
    <li><a href="/wiki/Hedge_apple" class="mw-redirect" title="Hedge apple">Hedge apple</a> (<i>Maclura pomifera</i>)</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get first ul after h2 tag has specify span with class is mv-headline.

From xpath, i have very simple soltuion:

```
$x('//span[@class="mw-headline"]/following::ul[1]')
```

But I don't know how select it in selector with get parent (.. in xpath) and next element (following::node in xpath) in my case.
Please give me a solution by CSS selector.

Thanks & Best Regards,

Phuong Hoang

Comment: In XPath, you can use the [parent axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp). In CSS, there is [no parent selector](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/).

Comment: @ObsidianAge: so could we have any other trick or solution to approach? As I know, css is more convinient than xpath.

Comment: In CSS there is no parent selector. You cannot select a parent in CSS.

Comment: At certain place it is best to use XPath and CSS won't work. So in your case XPATH is what you need

Answer (score -2):

You do one mistake in your XPath, xpath should be:

`$x('//h2[//span[@class="mw-headline"]]/following::ul[1]')`

Comment: What wrong with my code?
It run very well. you can see from here https://imgur.com/a/ztgvU